# Using Mat table in two different components, one Component mat table header cell colour is overflow in another component, how can fix it?

Tags: angular, angular6

In am using mat table in two different components, In one component header cell and row color overriding in another component.how can i fix it?

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="userTable_dataSource" matSort>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="userTable_displayedColumns"></tr>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="userType">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Tipo de User </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.userType}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          
          <ng-container matColumnDef="organization">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Organização </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{getOrganizationNameByID(row.organization)}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="updatedAt">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Último login </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.updatedAt | date:'HH:mm, dd/MM/y' }} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="userActionsColumn">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="white-space: nowrap;"> Acções </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <div class="row">
                <span class="mat-button-wrapper" (click)="openDialogViewUser(row)" style="cursor: pointer">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="color:#163b65">remove_red_eye</i>
                </span>
                <span class="mat-button-wrapper" (click)="openDialogEditUser(row)" style="cursor: pointer">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgba(22, 59, 101, 1)">edit</i>
                </span>
                <span class="mat-button-wrapper" (click)="openDialogRemoveUser(row)" style="cursor: pointer">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgba(22, 59, 101, 1)">clear</i>
                </span>
              </div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: userTable_displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
      </div>
```

Another component also like similar tables, how can fix header row and header cell color

Answer (score 0):

Use css:

```
th {
  background-color: red;
  ... 
  ...  
}
```